# My cordova apps stuck after instaling the plugin media

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, construct-2

I tried to build an cordova based android aplication, with "cordova-plugin-media" installed because I want my apps to be able to record my voice.
after the build success with no errors, I run the apps, the recording is working, but my apps become stuck.

The Cordova project was exported from Construct 2, and I've already checked the media permission on export. I've built the apps using SDK via CMD, and also add the "plugin-media" here.
before I add the plugin, the apps run well, but it can't record.
That's why I re-build it with plugin-media attached.

From the result export, I only edit the config.xml on my Cordova project.

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.mawar.speak" version="1.0.0.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Speech Platformer</name>
    <description>
        Aplication Description.
    </description>
    <author email="dummy@gmail.com" href="http://cordova.io">
        Node.js
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <!-- fullscreen -->
    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
    <!-- orientation -->
    <preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />
    <engine name="android" spec="~7.1.1" />
</widget>
```

What I want is to make my apps run well with plugin-media installed. But when I build with it, it's stuck as I run it on my device.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can you inspect and post the error log ?

Comment: the only error is, when I install my .apk on my device, and I run it with microphone permission allowed, I got my apps stuck on main menu. I can't inspect the error since it doesn't pops any error message while it stuck.

Comment: I am asking if you inspect your app and check what is the error?

Comment: I don't have any idea how to inspect my apps on my device. Do you have a clue how to inspect them? or where I can find the error log on my device?

Comment: Make sure your device is USB debug enabled and  open chrome://inspect/#devices then click on the console tab there you can see the errors.

Comment: finally I found the error on Chrome inspector:

`c2runtime.js:399 Uncaught TypeError: a.Jz is not a function
    at d (c2runtime.js:399)
    at l.ua.p.fg (c2runtime.js:402)
    at d.Hs (c2runtime.js:134)
    at d.Is (c2runtime.js:133)
    at d.ct (c2runtime.js:132)
    at d.Rb (c2runtime.js:132)
    at d.Rw (c2runtime.js:126)
    at d.eb (c2runtime.js:124)
    at hs (c2runtime.js:96)`

Comment: are you running a prod build ??

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't ensure whether it running on prod or not. maybe it's not. I build it using this command: `cordova build android` on the command prompt.